# How to Get all Dates Between Two Dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to display all the dates between two dates for a particular record

Table.

| JWDID | FromDate | ToDate | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 101 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-03 | 1500 |
| 102 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |

I need to output all dates with Quantity between FromDate & ToDate.

**Where FromDate >= '2022-06-01' AND ToDate <= '2022-06-30'**

Expected output :

| JWDID | Date | FromDate | ToDate | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-04 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-05 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 101 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-03 | 1500 |

guide me to write a query

Answer (score 3):

The key point here, is to have an "utility" table  with numbers from 0 to  a number (like 1000 or 10000, look for tally table on google : [1](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) , [2](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) ) and use it to join base on
`DATEADD(DAY, y.number ,T.FromDate)`

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
([JWDID] int, [FromDate] date, [ToDate] date, [Quantity] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([JWDID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [Quantity])
VALUES
    (100, '2022-06-01', '2022-06-05', 1000),
    (101, '2022-06-03', '2022-06-03', 1500),
    (102, '2022-06-29', '2022-07-03', 1800)
;    

WITH cteTally AS
(
    SELECT TOP(100) v.number
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values as v
    WHERE v.type = 'P'
    ORDER BY v.number ASC
)
SELECT  
    t.JWDID, 
    [DATE] = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,y.number,T.FromDate) AS DATE),
    FromDate = t.FromDate,
    ToDate = t.ToDate,
    t.Quantity
FROM #Table1 as t
    INNER JOIN cteTally as y
    ON t.ToDate > = DATEADD(DAY,y.number,T.FromDate)
;
```

The output:

| JWDID | DATE | FromDate | ToDate | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-02 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-04 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 100 | 2022-06-05 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-06-05 | 1000 |
| 101 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-03 | 2022-06-03 | 1500 |
| 102 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |
| 102 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |
| 102 | 2022-07-01 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |
| 102 | 2022-07-02 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |
| 102 | 2022-07-03 | 2022-06-29 | 2022-07-03 | 1800 |

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b884c50856b97ce0c680ef15224c0199)